# Hibernate OneToMany using annotations with legacy database

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

I'm working with a legacy database that isn't normalized at all. They've been coding relationships directly in the program (written in Uniface). Now, they are migrating to Java. Sadly, I can't change the database, but I need to map a OneToMany relationship between tables.

For instance, I have a table Invoice and a table Item.

Table **Invoice** has these keys. The first three of them are used as foreign keys for the relationship with Item:

```
invoice_serial_id,  
invoice_number_id,  
invoice_date,
invoice_otherkey1,
invoice_otherkey2
```

Table **Item** has these keys, the first three have the same type and value than their corresponding Invoice keys.

```
item_serial_id,
item_number_id,
item_date,
item_otherkey1
```

I have created the tables using reverse engineering from hibernate, which generated Invoice.java, InvoiceId.java, Item.java and ItemId.java, then manually created @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations. Here's the code so far:

**Invoice.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
public class Invoice implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2073462863929322522L;

    @EmbeddedId
        @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "invoiceSerialId", column = @Column(name = "INVOICE_SERIAL_ID", nullable = false, length = 9)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "invoiceNumberId", column = @Column(name = "INVOICE_NUMBER_ID", nullable = false, length = 9)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "invoiceDate", column = @Column(name = "INVOICE_DATE", nullable = false, length = 7)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "invoiceOtherkey1", column = @Column(name = "INVOICE_OTHERKEY1", nullable = false, length = 7)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "invoiceOtherkey2", column = @Column(name = "INVOICE_OTHERKEY2", nullable = false, length = 7))
    })
    private InvoiceId id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    private Set<Item> items;
}
```

**Item.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2840038244580784867L;

    @EmbeddedId
        @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "itemSerialId", column = @Column(name = "ITEM_SERIAL_ID", nullable = false, length = 9)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "itemNumberId", column = @Column(name = "ITEM_NUMBER_ID", nullable = false, length = 9)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "itemDate", column = @Column(name = "ITEM_DATE", nullable = false, length = 7)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "itemOtherkey1", column = @Column(name = "ITEM_OTHERKEY1", nullable = false, length = 7))
    })
    private ItemId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_SERIAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_SERIAL_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_NUMBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_NUMBER_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_DATE", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_DATE")
    })
    private Invoice invoice;
}
```

I get the following error:

```java
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(INVOICE_SERIAL_ID, INVOICE_NUMBER_ID, INVOICE_DATE) of com.just.an.stupid.example.app.Item.invoice referencing com.just.an.stupid.example.app.Invoice not mapped to a single property
```

I've also tried following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483026/hibernate-foreign-key-has-the-wrong-number-of-columns), and create a @joinTable on Invoice such as

```java
@JoinTable(name = "INVOICE_ITEM",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_SERIAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_SERIAL_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_NUMBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_NUMBER_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_DATE", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_DATE")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_SERIAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_SERIAL_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_NUMBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_NUMBER_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_DATE", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_DATE")
    }
)
```

but I got this:

```java
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.just.an.stupid.example.app.Invoice from com.just.an.stupid.example.app.Item has the wrong number of column. should be 5
```

How can I create a relationship using this database? Or should I give up and manually select Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to time constraints I wasn't able to wait for the right answer.

I ended up creating a view joining those tables in the example, as such:

```
create or replace table invoice_items as
select distinct
  i.field_1,
  i.field_2,
  i.field_3,
  it.field_4
from
  invoice i
inner join
  item it
on
  (i.invoice_serial_id = it.item_serial_id and
   i.invoice_number_id = it.item_number_id and
   i.invoice_date = it.item_date
  )
```

Then I mapped the view in Hibernate. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

YI think you need to do this.

1. Your invoice table has a primary key with corresponding @ID attribute.
2. The embedded ID in your invoice table should only contain the 3 fields that are present in the Item table.
3. Create an ItemID table, that mapps these three fields, and reference this in the Invoice table.

it will look like this....

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemId implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long serialNo;
private Long itemNumber;
    private Date itemDate
```

........
 with corresponding setters and getters, and overried the hashCode() and equals(Object o) for the ItemId class.

1. In your Invoice refer to this ItemId (like you are doing with embeddedId, and attribute overrides.

At the moment, you are embedding 5 fields in the foreign key definition, but only stress 3 in your itemID class. You don't need a join table, you are only creating a composite key class (containing the 3 fields) and embedding this in the invoice table.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer! Sadly I cannot do that since the tables will be used in other relationships. I guess I cannot do it the Right Way.