# How to join table and columns with JPA ?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have the next code:

When i want to join one column to employee table the join is made successfully! Here the working example of code :

Employee.class:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "employee")
public class Employee {

public Employee(int id, String name, String lastname, double salary, String spec) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.specialization = spec;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", salary=" + salary +
            ", spec='" + specialization + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "salary")
private double salary;

@Column (name = "specialization")
private String specialization;

public Managers getManagers() {
    return manager;
}

public void setManagers(Managers manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_from_managers_manager_id")
private Managers manager;

public Employee(){}
}
```

Manager class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "managers")
public class Managers {

public Managers(){}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Managers(String lastname, String name) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Managers{" +
            "lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "manager_id")
private int id;
}
```

[image]

When i want to join table with multiple columns i got exception, here the code:

Employee.class:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "employee")
public class Employee {

public Employee(int id, String name, String lastname, double salary, String spec) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.specialization = spec;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", salary=" + salary +
            ", spec='" + specialization + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "salary")
private double salary;

@Column (name = "specialization")
private String specialization;

public Managers getManagers() {
    return manager;
}

public void setManagers(Managers manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "managers" ,joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_from_managers_manager_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "name")})
private Managers manager;

public Employee(){}
}
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering employee.Employee from employee.Employee has the wrong number of column. should be 1
```

Can't understand the problem for Foreign key, what is going on behind the scene while joining the table with specified columns ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: Foreign key has the wrong number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483026/hibernate-foreign-key-has-the-wrong-number-of-columns)

Comment: Well, that simply doesn't make sense: 1. I guess a manager manages more than one employee, so it should be a ManyToOne. 2. The name column is already mapped by the name field, so it can't be mapped a second time by the association. 3. The name of the employee is not part of a foreign key to the manager. It's just the name of the employee, so why should it be used to map the association to the manager? 4. The manager is uniquely identified by its ID, and not by its ID + its name, so using an additional column as join column is useless. I have no idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: FWIW "Managers" should be called "Manager", since it represents one person.

Comment: Yes ! I am beginner with the relationships between tables/entities..