# Spring Boot - Batch Insert Forces Update Statement Execution

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert the records in batch in my MySQL table.

The Batch insert works like a charm when I do it without the composite key.

However, when I assign the composite key.

In my Table scheme: Id is the auto incremented primary key and ENODEB and HOUR_DATE_TIME are my normal columns that are not marked as composite key but I am making them composite in my Entity Class.

When I do this.

It executes select statements then Insert statements and finally executes update statements.

Since the records are not yet inserted in the database I get the error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned
> unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected:
> 1; statement executed: update idas_kpis set DL_PKT_LOSS_RT=?,
> DL_PKT_LOSS_RT_DEN=?, DL_PKT_LOSS_RT_NUM=?,
> D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN=?, D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM=?,
> D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE=?, V_ERB1_RET=?, V_ERB1_RET_DEN=?,
> V_ERB1_RET_NUM=?, D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN=?,
> D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM=?, D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE=?, V_RAN_ACC=?,
> V_RAN_ACC_DEN=?, V_RAN_ACC_NUM=?, Acc_S1_Succ_Rate=?,
> Acc_S1_Succ_Rate_DEN=?, Acc_S1_Succ_Rate_NUM=?, UL_PKT_LOSS_RT=?,
> UL_PKT_LOSS_RT_DEN=?, UL_PKT_LOSS_RT_NUM=?, cell_category=?,
> client_guid=?, HOUR_DATE=?, site_guid=?, venue_item_guid=? where
> ENODEB=? and HOUR_DATE_TIME=?

As I have checked on the internet, SaveAll method always checks for uniqueness based on the key defined in the entity class. Since its the first insert, the update should not be executed. Can someone help?

**Entity Class**

```
package com.vizalogix.insite.dx.entities.SVDXDB;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "idas_kpis")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value={"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@IdClass(IdasKpisId.class)
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class IdasKpis {

//    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
//    @GeneratedValue(generator = "idas")
//    @GenericGenerator(name = "idas", strategy = "increment")
//    @Column(name = "ID")
//    private Integer id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENODEB", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    String cell;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "HOUR_DATE_TIME", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    java.util.Date datetime;

   // private IdasKpisId kpisId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "HOUR_DATE")
    private Date date;

    /*@Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "HOUR_DATE_TIME")
    private Date datetime;

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "ENODEB")
    private String cell;*/

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "Acc_S1_Succ_Rate")
    private String D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "Acc_S1_Succ_Rate_NUM")
    private String D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "Acc_S1_Succ_Rate_DEN")
    private String D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "UL_PKT_LOSS_RT")
    private String D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "UL_PKT_LOSS_RT_NUM")
    private String D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "UL_PKT_LOSS_RT_DEN")
    private String D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "DL_PKT_LOSS_RT")
    private String D_DL_TP_L_ER_ECEL;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "DL_PKT_LOSS_RT_NUM")
    private String D_DL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "DL_PKT_LOSS_RT_DEN")
    private String D_DL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "V_RAN_ACC")
    private String D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "V_RAN_ACC_DEN")
    private String D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "V_RAN_ACC_NUM")
    private String D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "V_ERB1_RET")
    private String D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "V_ERB1_RET_DEN")
    private String D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "V_ERB1_RET_NUM")
    private String D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE")
    private String D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN")
    private String D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM")
    private String D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE")
    private String D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN")
    private String D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM")
    private String D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "client_guid")
    private String clientGuid;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "site_guid")
    private String siteGuid;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "cell_category")
    private String cellCategory;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "venue_item_guid")
    private String venueItemGuid;
}
```

**Insert Statement**

```
for (int i=0; i<csvArray.length(); i++) {
                IdasKpis kpi = new IdasKpis();
                IdasKpisId kpiId = new IdasKpisId();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf_time = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf_hour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
                java.util.Date hour = sdf_hour.parse(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HOUR").substring(10, 12));
                java.util.Date hour_time = sdf_time.parse(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HOUR"));
                java.sql.Date date_time = new Date(hour_time.getTime());
                java.sql.Date hours = new Date(hour.getTime());

                kpi.setDatetime(date_time);
                kpi.setCell(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("CELL"));

                kpi.setDate(hours);
                //kpi.setKpisId(kpiId);
                kpi.setD_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL (%)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL (%)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_S1_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_UL_TP_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL (%)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL (%)"): "0");
                kpi.setD_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_DEN(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_NUM(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RAN_ACC_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL (%)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL (%)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_DEN(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_NUM(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_OVR_RET_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL (%)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL (%)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_IRAFHO_SR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_RATE(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL (%)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL (%)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_DEN (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setD_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM(isNotEmpty(csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)")) ? csvArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("D_RACC_FR_L_ER_ECEL_NUM (#)") : "0");
                kpi.setClientGuid(clientGuid);
                kpi.setCellCategory("1");
                kpi.setSiteGuid(siteGuid);
                kpi.setVenueItemGuid(venueItem);

                kpiList.add(kpi);
            }
            kpiDao.saveAll(kpiList);
```

**Composite Key Class**

```
package com.vizalogix.insite.dx.entities.SVDXDB;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
public class IdasKpisId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ENODEB", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    String cell;

    @Column(name = "HOUR_DATE_TIME", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Date datetime;
}
```

Comment: Do not longer use SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date. This classes are outdated since many years. Use the new `java.time`API

Comment: is this causing the problem?

Comment: *Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1* The error meassage says, that the statement does not update any row.

Comment: this actually means that there is nothing the update as its updating before getting it inserted.

Comment: You should check it the values you set are the values you expect

Comment: I think you haven't checked the question completely. I am doing some mistake while configuring composite key.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `saveAll()` source code, its internally calling `save()` which in turn first of all checking if ongoing entity is new by doing null check :

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) { //here if you check `isNew` code, it checks for nullability of your `Id` attribute.
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity); //upsert 
        }
    }
```

Now, what I can see in your code, you mentioned your `Id` fields are non-nullable & that is reason, `save` call is going for upsert (here `em.merge`) even if its first record.

For your case, try removing `nullable = false` from your `Id` fields & see if that works as expected.

Comment: The issue still persist, it does not solve the problem :(

Comment: can you check if your db is having no records before this call?

Comment: Yes I checked it, there is no record before this call.

Comment: rechecked your question again, what I am thinking is your `IdClass` is wrong.  Can you do hashCode & equals implementation of IdasKpisId? , you might try using lomboks one or one which got generated with your IDE.. let me know once you implement equals & hashcode what it shows

Comment: I didnt get you? what do you mean by hashCode implementation?

Comment: I mean you need to implement equals & hashCode for `IdasKpisId` class.

Comment: can you please share a sample to guide? I am new to the language actually.

Comment: I think you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468498/idclass-jpa-annotation