# Should an error be thrown if a class is annotated with @Entity and @Embeddable?

Tags: java, annotations, jpa-2.0

Working on a JPA compliancy kit for my internship... Part of that kit is testing all corner cases.

I'm looking at `@Embeddable` today.
No attributes to deal with.

Then I started wondering...

What if a class is annotated with both `@Entity` and `@Embeddable`? I found this related question [A class that behaves like @Entity and @Embeddable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029745/a-class-that-behaves-like-entity-and-embeddable) that states `JPA does not allows @Entity and @Embeddable at the same time.` However, he's doing this in the context of an @ElementCollection, which is my guess as to what would be causing JPA not to like it (can't stuff non basic/embeddable types in there).

Basically,
According to JPA 2.0,
**Should an error be thrown if a class is annotated with both @Entity and @Embeddable?**
If not, what should happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From page 323 of JSR-317:

> Managed class to be included in the persistence unit and
>          to scan for annotations.  It should be annotated
>          with either @Entity, @Embeddable or @MappedSuperclass.

This is in reference to managed class definitions in a persistence unit. Based off that I do not believe it is valid to annotate a class with more than one of `@Entity`, `@Embeddable` or `@MappedSuperclass`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know documentation was hidden in the description of XML elements, though. Guess I'll have to read that aswell.